# Bold a specific word in a sentence in quotation marks in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so I was tasked to create a game in visual studio code using phaser.io for help. At the moment, I was told to bold a specific word in a sentence that is in quotation marks, but I am not sure how to do show. This is all in a Javascript file.

```js
const text3 = this.add.text(
  650,
  460,
  "Answer: Have a budget plan to save up money to buy it.",
  { fontFamily: "Roboto", fill: "black" }
);
```

I am suppose to bold the word "Answer" that is in quotation marks, so it should look like such

```js
const text3 = this.add.text(
  650,
  460,
  "**Answer**: Have a budget plan to save up money to buy it.",
  { fontFamily: "Roboto", fill: "black" }
);
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: What is `this.add.text` and where does it come from? Does it render HTML?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. Where does your text go?

Comment: sorry about that, I forgot to add the phaser text, but the this.add.text is used with the phaser framework, and it allows you to add text into the website

Comment: What does their documentation say?

Comment: Which version of Phaser are you using? This behaviour has changed from Phaser 2 (still used) to Phaser 3

Comment: I should be using phaser 3

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const text3 = this.add.text(
  650,
  460,
  "Answer: Have a budget plan to save up money to buy it.",
  { fontFamily: "Roboto", fill: "black" }
);

text3.addFontWeight('bold', 0); // 0 means the start of the text
text3.addFontWeight('normal', 6); // change it to normal starting from index 6 of the text
```

See: [Documentation](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Text.html#addFontWeight)

Comment: This is just for Phaser 2 and do not work on Phaser 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Phaser 3**

Inline styling of text is no supported natively, as per [this github issue](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/3390).

It's worth mention [rexBBCodeText & rexTagText](https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/37309-rexbbcodetext-rextagtext/) that could help you to manage inline style in a better way (using BBCode or html tags).

In any case, if you really need to use this syntax `**Answer**`, it's better to split the string and manage each part alone.

**Phaser 2 CE**

This old version manage text in a different way and you could use [`addFontWeight`](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Text.html#addFontWeight) specifying the beginning inside the string of the change in weight.

Comment: if I want to split the string, how do I split the string but keep them at the same line?

Comment: You need to manage the position of the parts with x and y positions. I think you could calculate the width of a text starting from number of characters and font size, or maybe diving into properties such as `width` and `displayWidth` of the text object https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Text.html